# Cannot assign int to dereferenced int in C

Tags: c, int, dereference

I am lost. I cannot assign an `int` to a dereferenced `int *`.

```
  printf("in octave\n");

  int *default_octave;
  printf("attr[%d]: %s\n",i+1,attr[i+1]);

  const char *octave_char = attr[i+1];
  printf("octave_char: %s\n", octave_char);

  int octave_number = atoi(octave_char);
  printf("octave_number: %d\n", octave_number);
  fflush(stdout);

  *default_octave=octave_number;
  printf("in octave pt 2\n");
  fflush(stdout);
```

This is the output:

```
in octave
attr[1]: 4
octave_char: 4
octave_number: 4
Segmentation fault
```

Why?

Running the GDB debugger gets to that line and then seg faults, too.

4

```
0            int octave_number = atoi(octave_char);
(gdb) s
41            printf("octave_number: %d\n", octave_number);
(gdb)
octave_number: 4
42            fflush(stdout);
(gdb)
43            *default_octave=octave_number;
(gdb) print octave_number
$1 = 4
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a7b in parse_song (song_data=0x7fffffffe7a8, attr=0x602600) at nullaby.c:43
43            *default_octave=octave_number;
(gdb)
```

I have no idea what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `int pointer`. Right.

It just mean you have a variable pointing to some memory area.
But you haven't allocated/reserved that memory area. So it can point to anything.

And it will surely point to a memory area you don't own, hence the segmentation fault.

You need to allocate memory for the pointer...

For instance:

```
 int * default_octave = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
```

Or you may also use:

```
int   default_octave_val;
int * default_octave = &default_octave_val;
```

Either you allocate memory to store your int (and then get a pointer to a valid memory area), or you create a pointer to an existing memory area (in the given example, a stack address).

Then you can de-reference that pointer, as it points to a valid memory area.
If it don't, you'll have a segmentation fault, or a bus error, depending on your OS.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a pointer epiphany.  Everything makes sense now about pointers and stack and heap...

Comment: Sure... : ) But here, there's no preferred way... It all depends on what the op is trying to achieve... As a pointer can point to just anything, it can point to a stack address or a heap address... It just need to point to a valid address if you want to dereference it...

Comment: An no problem about the vote count, as long as the op gets the answer he needs... : )

Answer (score 6):

It segfaults because you never initialise `default_octave` to point at anything that can store an `int`.

Comment: For example, you can assign the address of another `int` object, `default_octave = &another_octave`, or you can allocate memory for it yourself, , e.g. `default_octave = malloc(sizeof(int));` (which must later be freed with `free(default_octave);`, and allocating memory for just one `int` is not all that useful anyway).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I downvoted but have since removed. I see that you are a C expert and that this is an extremely basic problem for you. I do not feel, however, that this answer is useful to the OP. Nonetheless, you correctly identified the problem very shortly after James McLaughlin did.

Comment: @bernie: Fair enough.  My policy is to write the minimum post that answers the question; if the OP doesn't understand, they're always welcome to comment, and I will elucidate.

Comment: Agreed. It arguably doesn't make sense to flood the OP will information when a short answer will suffice. Thanks for sharing your viewpoint.